# LDAP query for checking group membership using C#

Tags: c#, ldap, ldap-query, group-membership

Having an `ldapConnection` established, I want to check if a given user is a member of a group given by name (note: I mean the "user frielndly" name, not a DN).

I've been experimenting with LDAP filter syntax for the first time and found out something that works, but it requires me to make two calls:

- first one to fetch my group's DN,
- another to check if a user is a member the group (given by its DN).

As I said, this works fine, but I'm wondering if this could be improved. In particular: maybe it's possible to solve the problem using a single query.

The work-in-progress version of my code is below. It's definitely not production-ready, but shows the big picture.

Last thing: when it comes to `userStore` value, I found it by trying and failing (mostly failing). The value I discovered seems to work, but please let me know if there's something better.

```cs
using var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(myServer, myPort));
var networkCreds = new NetworkCredential(myUserName, myPassword, myDomain);
ldapConnection.Bind(networkCreds);

var userStore = $"DC=domain,DC=local";
var groupSearchFilter = $"(sAMAccountName={myGroupName})";
var groupSearchRequest = new SearchRequest
                    (userStore, groupSearchFilter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, new string[] { "DistinguishedName" });

var groupDN = ((SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(groupSearchRequest)).Entries[0];

var searchFilter = $"(&(sAMAccountName={myUserName})(memberof={groupDN.DistinguishedName}))";
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
                    (userStore, searchFilter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, new string[] { "DistinguishedName" });
var response = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(searchRequest);
return (response.Entries.Count > 0);
```

Comment: that looks right for ldap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical LDAP server, like Active Directory you seem to be using, group membership is stored so that "Groups have members" (`member` attribute). The membership is reflected in the user (`memberOf` attribute).

But membership are stored using distinguished names. So to test for membership you must:

1. Find the `dn` attribute of your user
2. See if that `dn` is in the (multi-valued) `member` attribute of the group

You already get the DN of the group, but its `sAMAccountName` attribute is unique and indexed, use it as-is. Change that code to search for the user's DN instead with this filter:

```
var userSearchFilter = $"(sAMAccountName={myUserName})";
```

Extract from that the user's `dn` in a variable called `userDN` (for example). Then verify membership with this ldap search:

```
var searchFilter = $"(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName={myGroupName})(member={userDN.DistinguishedName}))";
```

Here I added the `objectClass` to the search. It is not required, but it could speed up the search if you have a whole lot of users and very few groups. For symmetry, you could add `(objectClass=user)` when you search for the user.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution searches for a group of which the user is a member and the example in my code does the opposite - searches for a user which belongs to a group provided.

Comment: At the end of the day I guess they both do the same thing, so thanks for explaining the details and confirming this is the right way to go.